# Possible to Find Total # of YouTube videos using YouTube API?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api

Does the API expose the number of total videos in the database to date? I've been trying to compile the number of YouTube videos for a research project.

So far, I've only found answers which are either: (1) outdated, or (2) speculative.

(An example: the researchers in this [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4539688) used the YouTube API with the "*" wildcard to find the total number of videos in 2007/2008.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The latest version of the API (v3) returns a maximum of 50 videos per page, and there is a soft limit imposed of about 500 videos per search query, down from about 1000 videos per search query in v2.